# how to display a .docx file in ckeditor?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am making a website in ASP.NET using C#. I have stored .docx file in database in binary form. I have successfully retrieved it but now my task is that I have to open .docx file from database in ckeditor. And if I make any changes then the file in the database should be updated.

Code for saving .docx file in DB...

```
private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string contenttype = String.Empty;

        //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".doc":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case ".docx":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case ".xls":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contenttype = "image/png";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                contenttype = "image/gif";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                contenttype = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }
        if (contenttype != String.Empty)
        {

            Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

            //insert the file into database
            string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" +
               " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
              = contenttype;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
            InsertUpdateData(cmd);
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." +
              " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";
        }
    }
```

Retrieving from DB...

```
private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
   {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
       .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
       SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Connection = con;
       try
       {
           con.Open();
           sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
           sda.Fill(dt);

           return dt;
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
       finally
       {
           con.Close();
           sda.Dispose();
           con.Dispose();
       }
   }

   private void download(DataTable dt)
   {
       Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
       Response.Buffer = true;
       Response.Charset = "";
       Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
       Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
       + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
       Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
       Response.Flush();
       Response.End();
   }

   protected void btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string s1 = proclist.SelectedItem.Value;
       string str1 = "";
       db.con.Open();
       try
       {

           string str = "select Name, ContentType, Data from tblFiles where Name='" + proclist.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
           db.com = new SqlCommand(str, db.con);
           SqlDataReader dr = db.com.ExecuteReader();
                 DataTable dt = GetData(db.com);
                   if (dt != null)
                   {

                       download(dt);
                   }
               }

       catch (NullReferenceException ex)
       {
           ex.ToString();
       }
       db.con.Close();
```

}

Comment: Maybe you can try to converting docx file to html and displaying in CKEditor for modify it. and again converting CKEditor content in docx  file

Comment: how can i do this? will you please help me? i am unable to find the solution

Comment: http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2014/11/25/screen-cast-convert-docxtohtml.aspx

Comment: this link generates error

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Wait for sec server is down

Comment: i think this error occurs when our connection is not created successfully. and this is the aspx page. will you please send me this code in a text file

Comment: I can't, I have server down too

Comment: ok then i am waiting. hopefully it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Javascript method:

```
function button_convertDocxToHTML_DisplayInCKEditor() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "Page.aspx/GetHTML",
        data: "{'pathFile':'UploadFolder/',
        'fileName':'docName',
        'extensionFile':'.docx'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            var resultHtml = result.d;

            var objEditor = CKEDITOR.instances["yourID_Description"];
            objEditor.setData(resultHtml);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // Unexpected error...
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

In the code-behind Page.aspx.cs, we have a web method in the side server. Maybe you will need some using like these: 
using System.Reflection; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetHTML(string pathFile, string fileName, string extensionFile)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            object path_DocsName = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(pathFile + fileName + extensionFile);

            object o = Missing.Value;
            object oFalse = false;
            object oTrue = true;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents docs = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;

            try
            {
                app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
                {
                    Visible = false,
                    DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
                };

                docs = app.Documents;
                doc = docs.Open(ref path_DocsName, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
                doc.Activate();

                string newHtmlFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("pathHtmlTEMPORAL/" + fileName + ".html");

                // Create html file
                doc.SaveAs(FileName: newHtmlFile, FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML);

                doc.Close(ref o, ref o, ref o);
                app.Quit(ref o, ref o, ref o);

                using (reader = new StreamReader(newHtmlFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
                {
                    result += reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = Resources.WholeSite.Validation_UnexpectedError + ": " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (doc != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
                if (docs != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docs);
                if (app != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
                if (reader != null) { reader.Dispose(); reader.Close(); }
            }

            return result; // this result has all html that you have to display into CKEditor.
        }
```